# German Stemmers in RTextTools

Tags: r, unicode, nlp, non-english

I am trying to use the German stemmer that comes with RTextTools but the results I get are quite off the mark.

Say, I have the following vector:

```
v <- c("groß", "größer", "am", "größten", "ähnlicher")
```

Using

```
library(RTextTools)
wordStem(v, "german")
```

I get

```
[1] "groß"    "größer"  "am"      "größten" "ähnlich"
```

What am I missing??

Comment: Well, apparently it should be using the Snowball algorithm (I checked it out here [link](http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/german/stemmer.html) - The first thing it should do is to replace "ß" with "ss" und then clearly "groß", "größer", "größten" should all result in "gross", "gross", "gross".

Comment: it looks as if the algorithm is not handled the "ß" properly. "ähnlich" is correct. Try it with "grösser" "grössten"

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm in Snowball

```
/*
    Extra rule for -nisse ending added 11 Dec 2009
*/

routines (
           prelude postlude
           mark_regions
           R1 R2
           standard_suffix
)

externals ( stem )

integers ( p1 p2 x )

groupings ( v s_ending st_ending )

stringescapes {}

/* special characters (in ISO Latin I) */

stringdef a"   hex 'E4'
stringdef o"   hex 'F6'
stringdef u"   hex 'FC'
stringdef ss   hex 'DF'
......
```

looks like it is translated back to 'DF' "ß"

Representation of umlaut by following e
The German letters ä, ö and ü, are occasionally represented by ae, oe and ue respectively. The stemmer here is a variant of the main German stemmer to take this into account.

The main German stemmer begins with the rule,

```
First, replace ß by ss, and put u and y between vowels into upper case.
```

This is replaced with the rule,

```
Put u and y between vowels into upper case, and then do the following mappings,

    (a) replace ß with ss, **"MAYBE WRONG ORDER"**
    (a) replace ae with ä,
    (a) replace oe with ö,
    (a) replace ue with ü unless preceded by q. 



So in quelle, ue is not mapped to ü because it follows q, and in feuer it is not mapped because the first part of the rule changes it to feUer, so the u is not found.
```